# Properly pass / remove data when setting / removing window subclass

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks, subclassing

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have multiple `edit control`s in a `dialog box` that need to accept floating numbers **and be `locale` aware.** I have decided to implement this behavior with `subclassing` the `edit control`s.

To achieve `locale` awareness I have decided to pass a structure to the [`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( it will hold data about decimal separator, negative sign and so on... ) as a `dwRefData` parameter.

The value of the fields is set in `WM_CREATE` **but they may change** if user changes settings in the `Control Panel->Regional and Language Settings` so I have decided to update the field's values in response to the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.

To avoid making this structure global, I have decided to make it `static` and declare it in the main window's procedure. I shall pass it to the dialog as the `LPARAM` argument of the `CreateDialogParam` API.

### PROBLEM:

I do not know how to properly pass the above described structure to `CreateDialogParam` and `SetWindowSubclass`.

The problem is also the proper removal of the `subclass` **so memory leaks can be avoided.**

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

After searching through Internet I failed to find anything useful, so for now I just have a conceptual solution.

It should look something like this:

```
//declare our structure that holds locale info
struct locale_structure
{
    wchar_t NegativeSign;
    wchar_t separator;
};

//in my main window procedure: 

static locale_structure MyStruct;

case WM_CREATE:
    {
        //get locale info about separator, negative sign and so on...
        MyStruct->separator      = //...
        MyStruct->NegativeSign   = //...
    }
    return 0L;

case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
    {
        //update locale info about separator, negative sign and so on...
        MyStruct->NegativeSign  =    //...
        MyStruct->separator     =    //...
        //...
    }

// in the WM_COMMAND, to the response to a button click, pass MyStruct:
    hwndSomeDlg = CreateDialogParam( ..., (LPARAM)MyStruct );
```

In my `dialog box` I should `subclass` / remove `subclass` like this:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        /******** This is the tricky part ***********/

        /// get locale structure from lParam
        locale_structure MyStruct = ( locale_structure )lParam;

        // pass it properly to subclassing procedures
        SetWindowSubclass( GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_EDIT1 ), ...,  MyStruct );
        SetWindowSubclass( GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_EDIT2 ), ...,  MyStruct );

        /************** other stuff ***********************/     
    }
    return TRUE;

case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        // perform proper cleanup to avoid memory leaks
        RemoveWindowSubclass( ... );
    }
```

### QUESTIONS:

1. How should I pass `MyStruct` to the `CreateDialogParam` and `SetWindowSubclass` ?
2. How should I remove `subclassing` **so I can avoid memory leaks**?
3. I assume that some memory allocating and deallocating will occur in `subclassing procedure` as well, can you instruct me how to do this properly?

### EDITED ON FEBRUARY 22nd, 2014

I am submitting the code that implements the concept described in the section *MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS*.

The program makes main window with a button that launches a dialog box. The dialog box contains two subclassed edit controls. Everything works fine, so my only concern now is if I am deleting structures properly.

Just make an empty project and copy/paste the required files:

In `resource.h` :

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by resource.rc
//
#define IDD_DIALOG1                     101
#define IDC_EDIT1                       1001
#define IDC_EDIT2                       1002

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1003
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

In `resource.rc` :

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 316, 180
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,159,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,259,159,50,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,23,20,94,17,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT2,23,65,90,21,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO 
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 309
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 173
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (U.S.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

In `main.cpp` :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";

// structure to hold locale info 
typedef struct LocaleInfo
{
    wchar_t NegativeSign[5];
    wchar_t DecimalSeparator[5];
}*pLocaleInfo;

// subclassing procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK Decimalni( HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, 
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData )
{
    pLocaleInfo li = ( pLocaleInfo )dwRefData;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
        {
            // accept digits,decimal separatorand negative sign
            // this validation is just an example

            if( ( isdigit(wParam) ) || ( wParam < L' ' ) )
                break;
            else
            {
                for( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
                    if( ( wParam == li->DecimalSeparator[i] )
                        || ( wParam == li->NegativeSign[i] ) )
                    {
                        return DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBeep(0);
                        return FALSE;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        // should I delete structure here ??
        RemoveWindowSubclass( hwnd, Decimalni, 0 );
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// dialog box procedure
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            {
                // subclass edit control
                pLocaleInfo li = ( pLocaleInfo )lParam;
                SetWindowSubclass( GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT1 ), 
                    Decimalni, 0, (DWORD_PTR)li );
                SetWindowSubclass( GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT2 ), 
                    Decimalni, 0, (DWORD_PTR)li );
            }
            return TRUE;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDOK:
                case IDCANCEL:
                    EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static pLocaleInfo li; // store decimal separator and minus sign

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            /************* load current locale settings *************/

            // max. len: language, country, code page
            wchar_t lpszLocale[64+64+16+3] = L""; 
            wchar_t lpszVal[128];

            LCID nLCID = ::GetUserDefaultLCID(); // current LCID for user
            if ( ::GetLocaleInfo( nLCID, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, lpszVal, 128 ) )
            {
                wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal ); // language
                if ( ::GetLocaleInfo( nLCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, lpszVal, 128 ) )
                {
                    wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, L"_" ); // append country/region
                    wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal );
                    if ( ::GetLocaleInfo( nLCID, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, 
                        lpszVal, 128 ) )
                    { 
                        // missing code page or page number 0 is no error 
                        // (e.g. with Unicode)
                        int nCPNum = _wtoi(lpszVal);
                        if (nCPNum >= 10)
                        {
                            wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, L"." ); // append code page
                            wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // set locale and LCID
            _wsetlocale( LC_ALL, lpszLocale );
            ::SetThreadLocale(nLCID);

           /*** get information for decimal separator and negative sign ***/

           li = new LocaleInfo;

           GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, 
               li->DecimalSeparator, 
               sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator) / sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator[0] ) );

           GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN, 
               li->NegativeSign, 
               sizeof(li->NegativeSign) / sizeof(li->NegativeSign[0] ) );

           /*** create a button that launches a test dialog box *****/

           HWND hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", 
               L"Test subclassed edit controls in dialog box", 
               WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
               50, 50, 350, 80, hwnd, (HMENU)8001, 
               GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
       }
       break;

    case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
        if( !wParam && !wcscmp( (wchar_t*)lParam, L"intl" ) )
        {
            // max. len: language, country, code page
            wchar_t lpszLocale[64+64+16+3] = L""; 
            wchar_t lpszVal[128];

            LCID nLCID = ::GetUserDefaultLCID(); // current LCID for user
            if ( ::GetLocaleInfo( nLCID, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, lpszVal, 128 ) )
            {
                wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal ); // language
                if ( ::GetLocaleInfo( nLCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, lpszVal, 128 ) )
                {
                    wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, L"_" ); // append country/region
                    wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal );
                    if ( ::GetLocaleInfo( nLCID, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, 
                        lpszVal, 128 ) )
                    { 
                         // missing code page or page number 0 is no error 
                         // (e.g. with Unicode)

                         int nCPNum = _wtoi(lpszVal);
                         if (nCPNum >= 10)
                         {
                            wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, L"." ); // append code page
                            wcscat_s( lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal );
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
            // set locale and LCID
            _wsetlocale( LC_ALL, lpszLocale );
            ::SetThreadLocale(nLCID);

            /** update information for decimal separator and negative sign ***/

            GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, 
                li->DecimalSeparator, 
                sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator) / sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator[0] ) );

            GetLocaleInfo (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN, 
                li->NegativeSign, 
                sizeof(li->NegativeSign) / sizeof(li->NegativeSign[0] ) );

            return 0L;
        }
        else
            break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if( LOWORD(wParam) == 8001 )
            {
                DialogBoxParam( GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, DlgProc, (LPARAM)li );
            }
        }
        return 0L;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        delete li;
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        g_szClassName,
        L"theForger's Tutorial Application",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 480, 320,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

### END OF EDIT

Thank you for your time and help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2 :**

Here's a working example (I hope):

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";

// structure to hold locale info 
typedef struct LocaleInfo
{
    size_t NegativeSize, DecimalSize;
    wchar_t *NegativeSign, *DecimalSeparator;
    LocaleInfo()
    {
        NegativeSize = 0;
        DecimalSize = 0;
        NegativeSign = NULL;
        DecimalSeparator = NULL;
    }
    ~LocaleInfo()
    {
        if (NegativeSign != NULL)
        {
            delete[] NegativeSign;
            NegativeSign = NULL;
        }
        if (DecimalSeparator != NULL)
        {
            delete[] DecimalSeparator;
            DecimalSeparator = NULL;
        }
    }
}*pLocaleInfo;

void ReallocateInfo(wchar_t *&InsideArray, size_t &InsideSize, size_t NewSize)
{
    if (NewSize == 0)
        return;

    wchar_t *NewArray = new wchar_t[NewSize];
    delete[] InsideArray;
    InsideArray = NewArray;
    InsideSize = NewSize;
}

// subclassing procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK Decimalni(HWND hwnd, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    pLocaleInfo li = (pLocaleInfo)dwRefData;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        // accept digits,decimal separatorand negative sign
        // this validation is just an example

        if ((isdigit(wParam)) || (wParam < L' '))
            break;
        else
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                if ((wParam == li->DecimalSeparator[i])
                    || (wParam == li->NegativeSign[i]))
                {
                    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBeep(0);
                    return FALSE;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        // should I delete structure here ??
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, Decimalni, 0);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// dialog box procedure
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // subclass edit control
        pLocaleInfo li = (pLocaleInfo)lParam;
        SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1),
            Decimalni, 0, (DWORD_PTR)li);
        SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2),
            Decimalni, 0, (DWORD_PTR)li);
    }
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static pLocaleInfo li; // store decimal separator and minus sign

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        /************* load current locale settings *************/

        // max. len: language, country, code page
        wchar_t lpszLocale[64 + 64 + 16 + 3] = L"";
        wchar_t lpszVal[128];

        LCID nLCID = ::GetUserDefaultLCID(); // current LCID for user
        if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, lpszVal, 128))
        {
            wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal); // language
            if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, lpszVal, 128))
            {
                wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"_"); // append country/region
                wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE,
                    lpszVal, 128))
                {
                    // missing code page or page number 0 is no error 
                    // (e.g. with Unicode)
                    int nCPNum = _wtoi(lpszVal);
                    if (nCPNum >= 10)
                    {
                        wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"."); // append code page
                        wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // set locale and LCID
        _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, lpszLocale);
        ::SetThreadLocale(nLCID);

        /*** get information for decimal separator and negative sign ***/

        li = new LocaleInfo;

        ReallocateInfo(li->DecimalSeparator, li->DecimalSize, GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, NULL, NULL));
        ReallocateInfo(li->NegativeSign, li->NegativeSize, GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN, NULL, NULL));

        GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL,
            li->DecimalSeparator,
            li->DecimalSize);

        GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN,
            li->NegativeSign,
            li->NegativeSize);

        /*** create a button that launches a test dialog box *****/

        HWND hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button",
            L"Test subclassed edit controls in dialog box",
            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            50, 50, 350, 80, hwnd, (HMENU)8001,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    }
        break;

    case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
        if (!wParam && !wcscmp((wchar_t*)lParam, L"intl"))
        {
            // max. len: language, country, code page
            wchar_t lpszLocale[64 + 64 + 16 + 3] = L"";
            wchar_t lpszVal[128];

            LCID nLCID = ::GetUserDefaultLCID(); // current LCID for user
            if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, lpszVal, 128))
            {
                wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal); // language
                if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, lpszVal, 128))
                {
                    wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"_"); // append country/region
                    wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                    if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE,
                        lpszVal, 128))
                    {
                        // missing code page or page number 0 is no error 
                        // (e.g. with Unicode)

                        int nCPNum = _wtoi(lpszVal);
                        if (nCPNum >= 10)
                        {
                            wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"."); // append code page
                            wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // set locale and LCID
            _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, lpszLocale);
            ::SetThreadLocale(nLCID);

            /** update information for decimal separator and negative sign ***/

            ReallocateInfo(li->DecimalSeparator, li->DecimalSize, GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, NULL, NULL));
            ReallocateInfo(li->NegativeSign, li->NegativeSize, GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN, NULL, NULL));

            GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL,
                li->DecimalSeparator,
                li->DecimalSize);

            GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN,
                li->NegativeSign,
                li->NegativeSize);

            return 0L;
        }
        else
            break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 8001)
        {
            DialogBoxParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, DlgProc, (LPARAM)li);
        }
    }
        return 0L;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        delete li;
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        g_szClassName,
        L"theForger's Tutorial Application",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 480, 320,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Everything is fine. You are right to delete it on `WM_NCDESTROY`, because it wil always be called (`WM_CLOSE` sometimes might be skipped). Still you forgot `{}` on `WM_CLOSE`, so there might be some problems when compiler decides you need problem.

Smart pointers should be used, because it should free memory for you in case something goes wrong, but it's up to you to choose. Also one good thing about them is that it is very easy to adapt to your code, you basically change nothing. One last thing, this "SmartPointer" is my creation and might still be incomplete, the other alternatives are `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and many more which can be found on internet.

There you go:

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SmartPointer.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";

// structure to hold locale info 
struct LocaleInfo
{
    wchar_t NegativeSign[5];
    wchar_t DecimalSeparator[5];
};

// subclassing procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK Decimalni(HWND hwnd, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    SmartPointer<LocaleInfo> *li = (SmartPointer<LocaleInfo>*)dwRefData;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
    {
        // accept digits,decimal separatorand negative sign
        // this validation is just an example

        if ((isdigit(wParam)) || (wParam < L' '))
            break;
        else
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                if ((wParam == (*li)->DecimalSeparator[i])
                    || (wParam == (*li)->NegativeSign[i]))
                {
                    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBeep(0);
                    return FALSE;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        // should I delete structure here ??
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, Decimalni, 0);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// dialog box procedure
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // subclass edit control
        SmartPointer<LocaleInfo> *li = (SmartPointer<LocaleInfo>*)lParam;
        SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1),
            Decimalni, 0, (DWORD_PTR)li);
        SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2),
            Decimalni, 0, (DWORD_PTR)li);
    }
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static SmartPointer<LocaleInfo> li; // store decimal separator and minus sign

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        /************* load current locale settings *************/

        // max. len: language, country, code page
        wchar_t lpszLocale[64 + 64 + 16 + 3] = L"";
        wchar_t lpszVal[128];

        LCID nLCID = ::GetUserDefaultLCID(); // current LCID for user
        if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, lpszVal, 128))
        {
            wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal); // language
            if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, lpszVal, 128))
            {
                wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"_"); // append country/region
                wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE,
                    lpszVal, 128))
                {
                    // missing code page or page number 0 is no error 
                    // (e.g. with Unicode)
                    int nCPNum = _wtoi(lpszVal);
                    if (nCPNum >= 10)
                    {
                        wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"."); // append code page
                        wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // set locale and LCID
        _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, lpszLocale);
        ::SetThreadLocale(nLCID);

        /*** get information for decimal separator and negative sign ***/

        li = SmartPointer<LocaleInfo>(LocaleInfo());

        GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL,
            li->DecimalSeparator,
            sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator) / sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator[0]));

        GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN,
            li->NegativeSign,
            sizeof(li->NegativeSign) / sizeof(li->NegativeSign[0]));

        /*** create a button that launches a test dialog box *****/

        HWND hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button",
            L"Test subclassed edit controls in dialog box",
            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            50, 50, 350, 80, hwnd, (HMENU)8001,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    }
        break;

    case WM_SETTINGCHANGE:
        if (!wParam && !wcscmp((wchar_t*)lParam, L"intl"))
        {
            // max. len: language, country, code page
            wchar_t lpszLocale[64 + 64 + 16 + 3] = L"";
            wchar_t lpszVal[128];

            LCID nLCID = ::GetUserDefaultLCID(); // current LCID for user
            if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, lpszVal, 128))
            {
                wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal); // language
                if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY, lpszVal, 128))
                {
                    wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"_"); // append country/region
                    wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                    if (::GetLocaleInfo(nLCID, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE,
                        lpszVal, 128))
                    {
                        // missing code page or page number 0 is no error 
                        // (e.g. with Unicode)

                        int nCPNum = _wtoi(lpszVal);
                        if (nCPNum >= 10)
                        {
                            wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, L"."); // append code page
                            wcscat_s(lpszLocale, 147, lpszVal);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // set locale and LCID
            _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, lpszLocale);
            ::SetThreadLocale(nLCID);

            /** update information for decimal separator and negative sign ***/

            GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL,
                li->DecimalSeparator,
                sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator) / sizeof(li->DecimalSeparator[0]));

            GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SNEGATIVESIGN,
                li->NegativeSign,
                sizeof(li->NegativeSign) / sizeof(li->NegativeSign[0]));

            return 0L;
        }
        else
            break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 8001)
        {
            DialogBoxParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hwnd, DlgProc, (LPARAM)li);
        }
    }
        return 0L;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        g_szClassName,
        L"theForger's Tutorial Application",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 480, 320,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

---

1. If I were you, I would want to pass a pointer (preferably a smart pointer, it can be from STD or custom made) structure trough `SetWindowSubclass()` or `CreateDialogParam()`. This way it would reflect on changes you make inside your structure across all of your windows. Some short program would be nice, as I don't have any dialog template nearby so I can't really give you an example on how to pass it to functions.
2. I think that removing sublassing on WM_CLOSE should work just fine.
3. A little more information would be good.

---

```
struct locale_structure
{
    wchar_t NegativeSign;
    wchar_t separator;
};

static SmartPointer<locale_structure> MyStruct;
```

---

```
#ifndef __SMART_POINTER
#define __SMART_POINTER

#include <wtypes.h>
#include <utility>

template <class Type>
class SmartPointer
{
private:
    void SmartDelete()
    {
        if (Pointer != nullptr && RefCount != nullptr && Size != nullptr)
        {
            if (RefCount[0] > 0)
                RefCount[0]--;
            else
            {
                if (Size[0] == 0)
                    delete Pointer;
                else
                    delete[] Pointer;
                delete RefCount;
                delete Size;
            }
            Pointer = nullptr;
            RefCount = nullptr;
            Size = nullptr;
        }
    }
    Type* Pointer;
    size_t* Size;
    UINT* RefCount;
public:
    UINT size()
    {
        if (Pointer != NULL && RefCount != NULL && Size != NULL)
        {
            if (Size[0] == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return Size[0];
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    SmartPointer() : Pointer(nullptr), Size(nullptr), RefCount(nullptr) {}

    Type& operator*() { return *Pointer; }
    const Type& operator*() const { return *Pointer; }

    Type* operator->() { return Pointer; }
    const Type* operator->() const { return Pointer; }

    Type& operator[](size_t index) { return Pointer[index]; }
    const Type& operator[](size_t index) const { return Pointer[index]; }

    template<typename ConversionType>
    operator ConversionType() { return reinterpret_cast<ConversionType>(this); }

    SmartPointer(Type& Object, size_t Size = 0)
    {
        RefCount = new UINT();
        this->Size = new size_t(Size);
        if (Size == 0)
            Pointer = new Type(std::move(Object));
        else
        {
            Pointer = new Type[Size];
            Pointer[0] = std::move(Object);
            for (size_t i = 1; i < Size; i++)
                Pointer[i] = Pointer[0];
        }
    }
    ~SmartPointer() { SmartDelete(); }
    SmartPointer(SmartPointer &&OtherSP)
    {
        if (Pointer != OtherSP.Pointer)
        {
            SmartDelete();
            Size = OtherSP.Size;
            Pointer = OtherSP.Pointer;
            RefCount = OtherSP.RefCount;
            OtherSP.Size = nullptr;
            OtherSP.Pointer = nullptr;
            OtherSP.RefCount = nullptr;
        }
    }
    SmartPointer& operator=(SmartPointer &&OtherSP)
    {
        if (Pointer != OtherSP.Pointer)
        {
            SmartDelete();
            Size = OtherSP.Size;
            Pointer = OtherSP.Pointer;
            RefCount = OtherSP.RefCount;
            OtherSP.Size = nullptr;
            OtherSP.Pointer = nullptr;
            OtherSP.RefCount = nullptr;
        }

        return *this;
    }
    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer &OtherSP)
    {
        if (Pointer != OtherSP.Pointer)
        {
            SmartDelete();
            Size = OtherSP.Size;
            Pointer = OtherSP.Pointer;
            RefCount = OtherSP.RefCount;
            RefCount[0]++;
        }
        else
            RefCount[0]++;
    }
    SmartPointer& operator=(const SmartPointer &OtherSP)
    {
        if (Pointer != OtherSP.Pointer)
        {
            SmartDelete();
            Size = OtherSP.Size;
            Pointer = OtherSP.Pointer;
            RefCount = OtherSP.RefCount;
            RefCount[0]++;
        }
        else
            RefCount[0]++;

        return *this;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: I have deleted previous comments to avoid discussion and because they are not relevant for the edited solution of yours. I agree with you with points `1` and `2` but I do not know what other info you need. Please ask me and I will update my question accordingly. Also, I thank you for your understanding and being "cool headed" about my previous comments. Best regards.

Comment: Well as I now said in my edited answer, If you could provide some core program with just working dialog creation functions I could give you an example. And about 3 question, are you talking about allocation/deallocation for passed structure?

Comment: Yes, I need to pass this structure to multiple `subclassing procedures`. Since this will involve conversion, I will have to allocate/deallocate memory to avoid memory leaks. Also, the structure will be declared as `static` in main window's procedure and sent to `dialog box` as `LPARAM`. I am a little busy with other things, but I will provide a working program as soon as possible. Thanks again. Best regards.

Comment: Converting struct/class from `LPARAM` to something else will create temporary variable (usually a pointer to structure provided by LPARAM), so there will be no allocation for you to worry about (unless you do it yourself). Having a simple static structure is also ok, but you would need to pass it by reference to change its variables globally, almost the same is with a pointer except that It can be NULL, but argument passed by reference can not (it must exist). Therefore I choose pointer and to be safe I use smart pointer to manage allocated memory for me in case I forget to delete it.

Comment: I believe everything will work fine. I will also put the deletion in `WM_DESTROY` instead of `WM_CLOSE` as you have suggested. Thank you for your time and help-I have officially accepted and upvoted your answer. Best regards until next time.

Comment: There is a small problem I ran into: Instead of using constant size for my `wchar_t` arrays, I wish to dynamically allocate them so I do not waste memory. I need to do that in my response to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` but once I change the language in Control Panel my app hangs. Apparently I am doing something wrong. Can you help me by showing me to properly release and realocate memory so my subclass procedure works properly? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: I'll write you a code in about ~1-2 hours, because I need to download and install Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you, but no need to hurry. You can also use `Format` method as a guideline from [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8294/CGridCellNumeric-A-numeric-cell-class-for-the-MFC) since it suits me. It uses `GetLocaleInfo` to get the required size of the array and allocate it, and then calls `GetLocaleInfo` to retrieve separators/digits/negative signs into array. You really need not hurry, since you must have other responsibilities regarding university and stuff...Best regards.

Comment: An example should work, but can not test it, because my locale remains the same, but my keyboard layout changes so it does not receive `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, you should try to fix this.

Comment: That is consistent behavior-you need to change the locale, not the keyboard. As far as I know, once you change the keyboard language you change the layout of the keys, but locale remains the same. It "gets" separator/currency/digits and other stuff from language settings not the keyboard ones. It's OK, we can "talk" in Saturday, when you have more time. Best regards.